# how to distinguish request and response packet in aws cloudWatch logs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

i hope your help.
My cloudWatch example is below.

[image capture: ssh connection logs with 172.0.0.10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oenH1.png)

As you see, cloudWatch is logging both of request and response packets.
In this case, everyone knows that packets displaying 22 as destination port is reponse packets because port 22 is well-known ssh server port.

However, if it is not a well-known port number, you will not be able to distinguish between request and response packets. How do you distinguish it in that case? The cloudwatch log alone does not show me how. No matter how I google it, I can not find a way. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

> In this case, everyone knows that packets displaying 22 as destination port is reponse packets because port 22 is well-known ssh server port.

That's not actually correct.  It's the opposite.

The server side of a TCP connection is using the well-known port, not the client¹ thus the well-known port is the destination of a request and the source of a response.

Packets with the *source* port of 22 would be the SSH "response" (server → client) packets.  Ports with the *destination* port of 22 would be the SSH "request" (client → server) packets.

When I make a request to a web server, my source port is ephemeral but the destination port is 80.  Responses come from source port 80.

But of course, the argument can be made that the terms "request" and "response" don't properly apply to packets, 
But rather they apply to what the packet contains -- and that is protocol specific.  In many cases, the client does the requesting and the server does the responding, but that correlation does not cleanly map down to the low layers of the protocol stack.

In the case of TCP, one side is always listening for connections, usually on a specific port, and that port is usually known to you, if not a "well-known" port, because you are the one who created the service and configured it to listen there.

As these flow log records do not capture the flags that are needed to discern the source and dest of the SYN... SYN+ACK... ACK sequence, you can't ascertain who originated the connection.

With no knowledge of the well-known-ed-ness or other significance of "port 22," it is still easy to conclude from your logs that 172.0.0.10 has a TCP socket listening on that port and that numerous other clients are connecting to it from their ephemeral ports... and we can confirm that this is still listening by running `netstat -tln` on that machine.

---

¹ *not the client* most of the time.  There are cases where a server daemon is also a client and will use the well-known port as its source port for outgoing connections, so source and dest might be the same in such a case.  I believe Sendmail might be an example of this, at least in some cases, but these are exceptions.